# Error in the android layout at com.facebook.widget.LoginButton

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I have imported the Facebook SDK as a library and made sure the jar is in the build path. I have rebuild the project couple of times but i could see there is an error in the line which uses the login button com.facebook.widget.LoginButton as shown in the below snapshot. Kindly advice me how to overcome this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line was missing in the XML

```
          xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

I have added it and the issue got solved.